# caffe:/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas

Tags: linux, caffe

I have installed BLAS in my CentOS7(64 bit).But when my use `make all` in my

'caffe'.It reports an eror:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcblas
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -latlas
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3] Error 1
```

I dont know why this happened and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using OpenBLAS to work around this problem.

```
yum install openblas-devel
sed -i 's/BLAS := atlas/BLAS := open/' Makefile.config
sed -i '/BLAS := open/aBLAS_INCLUDE := \/usr\/include\/openblas/' Makefile.config
```

which means install OpenBLAS and change `BLAS := altas` to `BLAS := open`
and add `BLAS_INCLUDE := /usr/include/openblas/` in `Makefile.config`. Once you have made these changes, rebuild.

Comment: It wasn't clear to me at first that you were posting an actual answer to this question. I tried to edit this into shape but you'll probably want to review. (Tangentially, I don't think the backslashes are necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

First issue

```
sudo yum install atlas-devel
```

and then add the following lines to your Makefile.config

```
BLAS_INCLUDE := /usr/include
BLAS_LIB := /usr/lib64/atlas
```

in the target shared library section. The section after adding the change looks like the following

```
 36 # The target shared library name
 37 LIBRARY_NAME := $(PROJECT)
 38 LIB_BUILD_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/lib
 39 STATIC_NAME := $(LIB_BUILD_DIR)/lib$(LIBRARY_NAME).a
 40 DYNAMIC_VERSION_MAJOR       := 1
 41 DYNAMIC_VERSION_MINOR       := 0
 42 DYNAMIC_VERSION_REVISION    := 0-rc3
 43 DYNAMIC_NAME_SHORT := lib$(LIBRARY_NAME).so
 44 #DYNAMIC_SONAME_SHORT := $(DYNAMIC_NAME_SHORT).$(DYNAMIC_VERSION_MAJOR)
 45 DYNAMIC_VERSIONED_NAME_SHORT := $(DYNAMIC_NAME_SHORT).$(DYNAMIC_VERSION_MAJOR).$(DYNAMIC_VERSION_    MINOR).$(DYNAMIC_VERSION_REVISION)
 46 DYNAMIC_NAME := $(LIB_BUILD_DIR)/$(DYNAMIC_VERSIONED_NAME_SHORT)
 47 COMMON_FLAGS += -DCAFFE_VERSION=$(DYNAMIC_VERSION_MAJOR).$(DYNAMIC_VERSION_MINOR).$(DYNAMIC_VERSI    ON_REVISION)
 48 
 49 BLAS_INCLUDE := /usr/include
 50 BLAS_LIB := /usr/lib64/atlas
```

I also faced the same problem when building caffe on the amazon deep learning ami and found the solution here: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/Pyfp9eQoIMQ

Answer (score 0):

`sudo yum install atlas-devel` to install the ATLAS library and try compiling Caffe again.

Comment: But I have installed it.

Comment: If so, were you able to locate this files?

Comment: I don't know.May be can't.

Comment: If you can't locate it, then it is not present! There is no issue in trying this answer once again

Answer (score 0):

1.Download atlas from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/math-atlas/files/latest/download?source=files)

2.Go to the root directory of the unzipped atlas. Install it using the instruction:

```
mkdir build
cd build 
../configure --shared
make
make install
```

3.Edit the `Makefile.config` file of caffe:

```
BLAS_LIB := /usr/local/atlas/lib/
```

`/usr/local/atlas/lib/` contains `libtatlas.so`